# WCF and Unity Interception : step by step tutorial

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, unity-container

I tried to follow this article and implement it in order to setup method interception in my WCF project : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc136759.aspx#S5

but there is no data types : PolicyInjectorFactory , PolicyInjector

can someone point me to an updated article ? or is it just that I'm doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look [here](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2010/05/15/Unity-dependency-injection-for-WCF-services-e28093-Part-1.aspx).

For services, you just need to inherit `ServiceHostFactory`.

Comment: in this example, he describes dependency injection, I really can't seem to figure out how to do interception for my service methods. is that possible ?